# D3 stacked bar sorting - chart only updating once

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm working on a D3 visualisation that uses a stacked bar. I'm trying to add in animation, so that the reader can sort the all the bars in descending order of values from a specific sub bar, and the chosen sub-bar moves closest to the axis. Eventually I'd like to have something like image attached.

[image: screen shot]

Sorting the bars as a whole is working fine every time i call my sort method, however the sorting of the sub-bars so that the selected measure is closest to the axis is only updating once. I have no idea why, but I've looked around and think it may be something to do with a key function, but I'm not sure how to integrate that in with the stack layout.

Here's how it looks right now - as you can see, the actual order of the stacked bars only rearranges once. [image: Here's a gif of it in action]

The data comes from a csv file - here is my code:

```
var dataset;

var causes = ["f_trans_rate", "f_violence_rate", "f_fireExp_rate", "f_fallSlipTrip_rate", "f_exposure_rate", "f_contact_rate", "f_allOther_rate"]
var firstCause = 0;

var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 300 };
var width = 1000;
var height = 10000;

svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var y = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]) // set y scale

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]); // set x scale

    // set the colors
    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    // load the csv and create the chart
    d3.csv("data/data.csv", function (data, i) {

    // calculate rates per 100k
    data.id = +i;
    data.f_violence_rate = +data.f_violence / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_trans_rate = +data.f_trans / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_fireExp_rate = +data.f_fireExp / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_fallSlipTrip_rate = +data.f_fallSlipTrip / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_exposure_rate = +data.f_exposure / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_contact_rate = +data.f_contact / +data.totEmp * +100000
    data.f_allOther_rate = +data.f_allOther / +data.totEmp * +100000

    data.f_total_rate = +data.f_violence_rate + +data.f_trans_rate + +data.f_fireExp_rate +
    +data.f_fallSlipTrip_rate + +data.f_exposure_rate + +data.f_contact_rate + +data.f_allOther_rate;

    return data;
}, function (error, data) {

    if (error) throw error;

    data.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_total_rate, b.f_total_rate));
    y.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.occupation; }));
    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.f_total_rate; })]).nice();
    z.domain(causes);

    dataset = data;

    drawChart();

});

function order(data) {
    order = [+0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6]
    order.splice(firstCause, 1); // remove
    order.unshift(firstCause) // put at front
    return order;
}

function update(fCause) {
    firstCause = fCause;
    dataset = [...dataset];

    var sortFn;
    switch (firstCause){
        case +0: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_trans_rate, b.f_trans_rate);
            break;
        }
        case +1: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_violence_rate, b.f_violence_rate);
            break;
        }
        case +2: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_fireExp_rate, b.f_fireExp_rate);
            break;
        }
        case +3: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_fallSlipTrip_rate, b.f_fallSlipTrip_rate); 
            break;
        }
        case +4: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_exposure_rate, b.f_exposure_rate);
            break;
        }
        case +5: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_contact_rate, b.f_contact_rate); 
            break;
        }
        case +6: {
            sortFn = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.f_allOther_rate, b.f_allOther_rate); 
            break;
        }
        default: console.log('default')
    }

    const yCopy = y.domain(dataset.sort(sortFn).map(d => d.occupation)).copy();
    // define what will do the transition
    const t = d3.transition().duration(1000);
    const t2 = d3.transition().duration(1000);

    const groups = d3.selectAll("g.bar-group")
        .data(d3.stack().keys(causes).order(order)(dataset, firstCause)
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return z(d.key); });

    const bars = groups.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(d => d, d => d.data.occupation)
        .sort((a, b) => yCopy(a.data.occupation) - yCopy(b.data.occupation))

    // sort order of stack
    t.selectAll("g.bar-group")
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d[0]);
        })
        .delay(0)

    // sort data y axis - needs seperate transition so bars move first
    t2.selectAll("g.bar-group")
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("y", function (d) { return yCopy(d.data.occupation) })
        .delay(1000)

    // sort label y axis
    t.select(".axis.y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .selectAll("g")
        .delay(1000)

    g.selectAll("g.bar-group").transition()
        .filter(function() {
          return !this.classList.contains('bar')
        })
        .duration(200)
        .attr("opacity", 175)   
}

function sortBy(i){console.log(i); update(i)} // i is 0-6

function drawChart() {
    console.log(dataset)
    g.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3.stack().keys(causes)
            .order(d3.stackOrderAscending)(dataset))
        .enter().append("g")
            .classed("bar-group", true)
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return z(d.key); })
        .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .classed("bar", true)
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.data.occupation);
            })
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d[0]);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
            })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
}
```

It's a bit lengthy, but essentially the chart is created as a stacked bar, and then the sort method should rearrange the bars by calling update, but only works once.

TIA for any help or comments :)

Comment: you have a very big monitor, svg height = 10000, where is the example csv?

Comment: it's a very long dataset so that was just so i could see the bars easily right now - I've added a gif of it working for you, and a link to the source :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem is the definition of your order function

```
function order(data) {
    order = [+0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6]
    order.splice(firstCause, 1); // remove
    order.unshift(firstCause) // put at front
    return order;
}
```

After 1 call you have redefined `order`, it is no longer a function anymore. Passing this to `stack.order(order)` will not work.

Use a new variable inside the function, it could work with `var order` but that is adding also confusion.

```
function order(data) {
    var orderNew = [+0, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6]
    orderNew.splice(firstCause, 1); // remove
    orderNew.unshift(firstCause) // put at front
    return orderNew;
}
```

Your dataset has a lot of duplicates in the `occupation` column. Why? (the only difference is whitespace)

Comment: thank you so much! it always seems to be something so small like this, but it makes sense now. Still pretty new to D3. And yeah, it needs cleaning up a bit - it's a big dump pulled from the BLS, which has a lot of duplication in where different occupation codes have the same occupation name. Thanks again!